# How to use insert with on_conflict_do_nothing in FastAPI, SQLAlchemy core, Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

Im trying to implement insert with on_conflict_do_nothing statment but geting an error

```
2023-12-05 13:01:46 AttributeError: 'Insert' object has no attribute 'on_conflict_do_nothing'
```

I am using FastAPI SQLAlchemy core with Postgres

crud.py file

```
from app.db import client, osr, bids, database

async def join(payload):
    insert_values = {'name': payload.name, 'code': payload.code}
    insert_stmt = client.insert().values(
        insert_values
    )
    on_conflict_stmt = insert_stmt.on_conflict_do_nothing(
        index_elements=['leiCode']
    )
    return await database.execute(query=on_conflict_stmt)
```

app/db.py file

```
import os
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    UniqueConstraint,
    DateTime,
    Date,
    Integer,
    MetaData,
    String,
    Table,
    ForeignKey,
    create_engine,
    text
)
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
from databases import Database

DATABASE_URL = os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")

# SQLAlchemy
engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)
metadata = MetaData()


client = Table(
    "bids",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column("name", String(50), nullable=False),
    Column("code", Integer),

# databases query builder
database = Database(DATABASE_URL)
```

> stmt = insert(my_table).values(id='some_id', data='inserted value')
> stmt = stmt.on_conflict_do_nothing()
> print(stmt)
> https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.Insert.on_conflict_do_update

Probably insert that I use for client object 'client.insert()' is,not the same as in documentation but I get same error when use

```
from sqlalchemy import insert
insert_stmt = insert(client)...
```

Comment: can you try:
`from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert`
`insert_stmt=insert(client).values(insert_values).on_conflict_do_nothing(index_elements=['leiCode']`

assuming you are using postgres...

Comment: (the reason is that `on_conflict_do_nothing` is a Postgres specific feature, so you need to use the `Insert` class from the postgres compatibility module: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.Insert

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PostgreSQL, you can try using the on_conflict_do_nothing method directly on the Table object rather than the Insert object.

```
from app.db import client, osr, bids, database

async def join(payload):
    insert_values = {'name': payload.name, 'code': payload.code}
    
    # Assuming `client` is your Table object
    insert_stmt = client.insert().values(insert_values)
    
    # Assuming you have a 'leiCode' column in your table
    on_conflict_stmt = insert_stmt.on_conflict_do_nothing(
        index_elements=['leiCode']
    )

    return await database.execute(query=on_conflict_stmt)
```